# Map object from form to Model in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am busy with sending through form values to my backend, now i first want to map it to a model and then send that model to the backend. Here is my model:

```
    export class PlayerRegistration {
  public  mainRegistrationInfoId: string;
  public  playerIdType: string;
  public  playerIdNumber: string;
  public  contactNumber: string;
  public  occupation: string;
  public  experienceLevel: string;
  public  challengeFoundSource: string;
  public  hadCompletedPreviously: boolean;
  public  playerId: string;
}
```

And this is what I get back from my Form in console:

```
Object { identityType: 0, identificationNumber: "testID", contactNumber: "12", occupation: "Test", experienceLevel: "Professional", foundChallenge: "Social Media" }
```

Now all I want to do is map the values in my function before I send it to the service:

```
  public register(value) {
    console.log(value);
    /*this.isRegistering = true;
    this.userService.enterMainChallenge(value)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
      )
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          this.isRegistering = false;

        },
      );*/

  }
```

Comment: and how do you defined your form? Is it a FormGroup?

Comment: @AlleXyS It is like this `<form class="register-form" #form="ngForm" (submit)="register(form.value)">`